# No product return with getEntitlements after latest build rejected

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I have one build in store that is already approved and is included with in-app purchase.

I decided to submit a new build, and it was rejected. But now the previous build in the store seems like not returning any product with `getEntitlements`.

I tested with Android which is also using RevenueCat and it works just fine. So my question is, is it possible for the latest rejection of build affect previous build's in-app purchase ?

Comment: It could be a problem with the state of the products in App Store Connect. What state are they showing? They need to be in the 'Approved' state before you can use them in production.

Comment: The product state is till 'Approved', just the build is 'Rejected'.